I'm making a streaming site using Raspberry Pi 4 flask, but only black screen is sent
Looking to create a streaming site with the Raspberry Pi4 webcam. The webcam used the camera module 2. The web page works fine, but the streaming video only has a black screen taken out.
https://i.sstatic.net/MBWF6mup.jpg
https://i.sstatic.net/82c4hmQT.jpg
The flask code is the main code in the streaming folder and the html file in the templets folder
What could be the problem?
It's the flask main code.
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template
import cv2
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

def generate_frames():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
    
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Error: Could not open webcam.")
        return
    
    while True:
        success, frame = cap.read()
        if not success:
            print("Error: Failed to read frame from webcam.")
            break
        
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        if not ret:
            print("Error: Failed to encode frame.")
            continue
        
        frame = buffer.tobytes()
        
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
        
        time.sleep(0.1)  
    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')  

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

and HTML code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Video Streaming with Flask</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }
        .container {
            max-width: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h1 {
            color: #333;
        }
        #video-stream {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Live Video Streaming with Flask</h1>
        <img id="video-stream" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" width="640" height="480" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>


Raspberry Pie 4 didn't recognize the camera so it didn't stream. I tried it again on Raspberry Pie 3 B+ and it's working fine
